# how to animate points of a UIBezierPath in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, animation, shapes, cgpoint

I have the following code that draws a custom shape. but i want to animate the points of this shape based on a value in this case the value is called movementX or movementY. So every time i call the function shapeVoid i want the points to move in a spesific direction based on the movement values. how do i do this? see my code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {    

var movementX: CGFloat = 0.0
var movementY: CGFloat = 2.2


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    movementUpdate = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("ShapeVoid"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}


func ShapeVoid(){
    view.layer.addSublayer(shape)
    shape.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 120/255, blue: 200/255, alpha: aValue).CGColor
    shape.lineWidth = 2
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    let shapePath = UIBezierPath()
```

i want to animate the points of my shape path. see below i added a value called movementX/ movmentY to move the points but this didnt do anything. how would i animate points of a path?

```
    shapePath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(200, 200))
    shapePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(230 + movementX, 250 + movementY))
    shapePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(150 + movementX, 300 + movementY))
    shapePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(100 + movementX, 280 + movementY))
    shapePath.closePath()
    shape.path = shapePath.CGPath
}
}
```

thanks in advance let me know if something is unclear :)

Comment: You don't appear to ever be changing movementX and movementY. Are these set somewhere else?

Comment: no i dont want to change the values of movementX and Y. i want to move the CGPointMake based on the value of movementX and movementY. so every 0.5 seconds i want to add 2.2 to  the x-value of CGPointMake